# Configure request timeout in Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want requests to timeout after some time, say 20 seconds.  If the application takes longer than 20 seconds to send a response, Phoenix should cancel execution and immediately reply with some error (preferably an HTTP 503).

I've scoured the Phoenix docs but couldn't find any mention of a request timeout option. It looks like Cowboy has a `:timeout` option, which I tried setting to 10 ms, but it still allowed a request to take 8951 ms:

```
config :app, SomeApp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4000, timeout: 10]
```

It turns out the Cowboy docs define this option as:

> Time in ms with no requests before Cowboy closes the connection.

which is not what I'm looking for.

Is it possible to set a request timeout in Phoenix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by no means a responsibility of the web-server/framework. Cowboy has no clue (and it should not have!) about what’s going on in the application, it *serves the connections*. Phoenix could take care of that, but it would violate [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). After all, the aforementioned timeout is more about the business logic. Imagine cowboy/phoenix would be trying to handle timeout: what should happen with the *currently executing handler*?

That said, *the application* should handle this kind of timeout and it’s relatively easy: one just needs to wrap the underlying execution in the task with a timeout you want. That way it would be flexible, reliable and you might specify which controllers/actions should behave that way, and which should not.

In a pseudocode (it’s a real code, but I did not test it):

```rb
def create(conn, params) do # or any other action
  fn -> prepare_result end
  |> Task.async()
  |> Task.yield(10)  # ⇐ HERE!!!
  |> case do
    {:ok, result} -> # success
      conn
      |> put_status(200)
      |> json(%{ok: result})
    nil -> # not finished yet; do smth with the task itself!
      conn
      |> put_status(503)
      |> json(%{error: :timeout})
    {:exit, reason} -> # should not happen [see Task.yield/2 docs]
      conn
      |> put_status(500) # internal server error; unexpected
      |> json(%{error: reason})
  end
end
```

[`Task.yield/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#yield/2).

---

*Sidenote:* of course, if you need this behaviour across the whole application, just declare a macro doing that, or like.

Comment: Sidenote: SRP = Single Responsibility Principle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: @raarts thanks, I thought this acronym is widely known; I put the link directly into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this..

```
config :app, SomeApp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4000, timeout: 10]
```

doesn't work.. Try changing to..

```
config :app, SomeApp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4000, protocol_options: [idle_timeout: 10_000]]
```

Comment: Worth noting that `idle_timeout` is only available in Cowboy 2.0+